# Updating local variables in jetpack compose and side effects

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, side-effects

Reading about side effects in jetpack compose ([thinking in compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model)), I find this example:

```
@Composable
@Deprecated("Example with bug")
fun ListWithBug(myList: List<String>) {
    var items = 0

    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
        Column {
            for (item in myList) {
                Text("Item: $item")
                items++ // Avoid! Side-effect of the column recomposing.
            }
        }
        Text("Count: $items")
    }
}
```

As described in context of this example, this is incorrect, since it is not allowed to modify the local variable `items`. Now I wonder, what is allowed and what not. How does compose know, that it can evaluate the `item in myList` in parallel? Would it be allowed, if `var items` was moved into the `Column`-scope?

Even further, is updating variables allowed at all? Could we do something like:

```
class LongLastingClass() {
   var someState = mutableStateOf(0) 
      private set
    
   fun update(value: Int) {
      someState = value
   } 
}

@Composable
fun ListWithUpdate(value: Int) {
   val longLastingObject = remember{ LongLastingClass() }
   longLastingObject.update(value) 
   ...
}
```

Or would the `update` have to be moved to something like a side effect? Or is this construct a problem, since we better should not modify state-variables within a composable, so a side effect would be needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring `Row` and `Column` for now, as they are inline functions and which are special, you should never write code in Compose that is dependent on when a composable lambda will execute. It may not produce the result you were expecting.

If you changed the above to,

```
@Composable
@Deprecated("Example with bug")
fun ListWithBug(myList: List<String>) {
    var items = 0
    A {
        B {
          for (item in myList) {
            Text("Item: $item")
            items++ // Avoid! Side-effect of the column recomposing.
          }
        }
        Text("Count: $items")
    }
}
```

This code is only valid if every line calling `ListWithBug` always calls `A` invoking its lambda which always calls `B` invoking its lambda. If `A`'s lambda is invoked and `B` is skipped then the value of `items` will be `0` when `Text("Count: $items")` executes. In other words, this code only works if `B` doesn't skip and the lambda passed to `B` doesn't skip, whenever `ListWithBug` is executed.

Parallelism is not required for this code to be wrong, just skipping.

This way around this not use Compose to count. If you changed this to,

```
@Composable
fun WorkingList(myList: List<String>) {
    A {
        B {
          for (item in myList) {
            Text("Item: $item")
          }
        }
        Text("Count: ${myList.size}")
    }
}
```

it produces the same result without relying when or if a composable lambda will executed.

Comment: This makes things much more clear. So this would mean, that moving the `var items = 0` into the `Column`-scope (ignoring that it is an inline function) would make the code valid. And also variable updates as described in the second example is correct code. Right?

Comment: The code would work but I still don't consider this valid code. In general, do not use var locals in a composable function as it is almost never correct and in the cases it works it highly likely that any change to the function will cause it to break in the future. You should never use composition to produce intermediate results as these results are likely to be invalid as composition function are not guaranteed to run the usual sequence. Produce complete results in the view model instead and use composition to visualize these results.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that state logic should be kept outside. In the end this is more for understanding. If it comes to animated transitions between states, I guess it is important to understand how to update state within composables ...

Comment: "  ...it is important to understand how to update state within composables": 

Don't update state in a composable. Use a coroutine or some other mechanism to update the state which compose will react to.